# Searching with Lucene with stemming enabled

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Suppose I store a set of strings (each document in Lucene would be a single word), and then given an input word W, I would like to retrieve all the document that not only match word W but also those documents whose stemmed version also matches W.

Also, suppose a input a word W, I would want to take care of the case where there is a document that matches the stemmed version of the word W as well.

Would writing my own custom analyzer and returning a PorterStemFilter suffice? Do I need to just write this class and reference it as the analyzer in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a custom Analyzer that has a stemmer in the analyzer chain should suffice.

Here is the sample code that uses [PorterStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/PorterStemFilter.html) in Lucene 4.1

```
 class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new LowerCaseTokenizer(version, reader);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, new PorterStemFilter(source));
  }
}
```

Please note that you MUST use the same custom Analyzer while querying which is used for indexing as well.

You may find the sample code for your version of Lucene in the corresponding PorterStemFilter documentation.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I have a doubt here. If two words stem to the same word, wouldn't that cause precision issues?

Comment: Yes, using stemming will improve the recall at the expense of precision. The programmer/designer should make a decision based on requirements particular to the problem domain.